# External touch screen input only uses cursor coordinates

Tags: android, coordinates, touchscreen

I have a ViewSonic touch screen display connected to an Android PC (kernel 3.0.36+) via HDMI & USB.  The display shows everything correctly.  Furthermore, the Linux kernel recognizes it.

dmesg:

```
<6>[   99.699034] usb 2-1.2.3: new full speed USB device number 8 using usb20_host
<6>[   99.800896] usb 2-1.2.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0408, idProduct=3008
<6>[   99.800993] usb 2-1.2.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=4
<6>[   99.801099] usb 2-1.2.3: Product: OpticalTouchScreen
<6>[   99.801169] usb 2-1.2.3: Manufacturer: Quanta
<6>[   99.801226] usb 2-1.2.3: SerialNumber: 0000
<4>[   99.805402] quirks: 0x00000000
```

The problem is that the screen, while I can touch anywhere, only registers the tap at the curser location (wireless keyboard/mouse connected).  If I move the cursor and tap anywhere on the screen, the new location receives the tap.  If I remove the keyboard/mouse dongle the behavior remains, but now I can't move the cursor.

The USB connection to the monitor is being displayed (highlighted) in `dev/usb`:

[image]

Input device configuration file located in `/system/usr/idc/Vendor_0408_Product_3008.idc`

```
# Input device configuration file.


# This is an external device, attached to the USB or Bluetooth bus.
device.internal = 0

# The device should behave as a touch screen, which uses the same orientation
# as the built-in display.
touch.deviceType = touchScreen
touch.orientationAware = 0
touch.gestureMode = spots

# Orientation
touch.orientation.calibration = vector

# Output Ranges
output.width = 1920
output.height = 1080
output.diag = sqrt(output.width ^2 + output.height ^2)
```

Any guidance or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Comment: @Mr.Hyde  Not for this particular monitor.  It works fine with certain Viewsonic models though.

Comment: And why "touch.gestureMode = spots" doesn't work?! So I'm force to check "Show touches" in developer options!

Comment: @Mr.Hyde - I think these are driver issues - given that it works with the Viewsonic monitor we are using.  Actually works very well with the Viewsonic monitor!

Comment: I'm using Standard general HID TouchScreen driver! But maybe you're right :/